# Aplicação Delphi 10 Seatle não abre

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe8

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em delphi 10 seatle com bd firebird e ela compila e roda normalmente. Porém quando coloca em outro computador ela dá um erro e aparece o endereço da memória. Se eu instalar o delphi 10 seatle nesse computador que a aplicação não abre, a aplicação já abre normalmente o .exe, sem nem mesmo a necessidade de abrir o projeto pelo delphi. Dei uma olhada pra ver se na instalação do delphi ele cria alguns arquivos na pasta do windows para que eu pudesse copia-los as outras máquinas, mas infelizmente ainda não consegui desvendar esse mistério.

Comment: Se você instala o Delphi e aplicação funciona significa que a instalação do Delphi esta instalando os Drivers de comunicação com o Banco, em outras palavras você precisa das DLLs responsáveis pela conexão (Componente X Banco). Como você não postou Nem um detalhe, essa é minha resposta básica!

Comment: se você usar FireDac não precisa de DLL

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem ?

Seria muito bom você informar a mensagem de erro para facilitar a compreensão e entender o problema.

**Possíveis problemas:**

**1** Sua aplicação está faltando DLL que são usadas pela sua aplicação, como disse
Junior Moreira.

**2** Verifique se seu SGDB está rodando ou se a DLL do Firebird está na raiz onde está a aplicação ".exe"

> Sem mais informações de erro ou dados sobre isso, irei acabar falando besteira.

**Espero ter ajudado.**